# how to create a new user for visual svn server using svnkit javaapi?

Tags: svn, java, visualsvn-server

I want to create a new user in the visual-svn server using java svnkit API.

I want to add that user to one group programatically.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I suspect that you can't, having read [this](http://old.nabble.com/API-to-add-create-a-new-user-on-SVN-td20203094.html)